# insert huge data with duplicate using entity framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework-core

I'm using `.NET Core 2.0` with Entity Framework Code First. I have a table "HData" with these few attributes: Id(PK), Value(Index with ignoring duplicate key setting) and Time. This table may have 10,000,000+ entries.

I insert thousand of entries like this:

```
dataList.ForEach(i => db.HData.Add(new HData() { Value = i, Time = some.CreateDateTime }));
db.SaveChanges();
```

I've already set the `IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON` with SQL command, but when the code run until above `db.SaveChanges`, it shows me the duplicate error message as:

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.HData' with unique index 'IX_HData_Value'. The duplicate key value is (abcde).

How can I solve it or anyway can catch this exception and skip to next data insert?

Update HData Models Information

```
public class HData 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public DateTime Time { get; set; }

}
```

OnModelCreating:

```
builder.Entity<HData>(b => {
   b.Property(p => p.Time).HasDefaultValueSql("GETUTCDATE()");
   b.HasIndex(p => p.Value).IsUnique(true).HasFilter(null);});
```

3rd Update:

I set the `IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON` in `EnsureSeedData` function, the code below

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("ALTER INDEX [IX_HData_Value] ON [dbo].[HData] REBUILD WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON)");
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Have you tried using a Guid as key

Comment: @3dd you mean change the attribute Id to Guid or ?

Comment: Can you send the code for the HData model?

Comment: @el_M updated the HData model and onmodelcreating setting

Comment: if the ID's are unique, why not remove the .isUnique(true) from the index and instead add the [Key] attribute to the ID?

Comment: @el_M  before this, i check if exist from table every entry i insert, but it very slow, so i'ld like to use the sql to help me skip the duplicate data and i dont remove the .IsUnique(true) of Value index

Comment: How do you set `IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON`? Please show *all* relevant code. It's not clear whether setting this option has any effect on the session executing the actual insert statements (I think it hasn't). Also, why don't you sanitize `dataList` first, for instance by converting it to a `HashSet`?

Comment: @GertArnold i've updated the information how i set IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON

Comment: I don't know why I can't catch the `DbUpdateException` , it always `Object reference not set to an instance of an object Exception` first

Comment: same poblem in .NET Core 3.0. Have you found out the issue?

Comment: @Abdulkarim Kanaan I use another method to deal it

Answer (score 0):

You can create a loop with the condition until the count of all records.
and use try-catch.

Sample code :

```
var data= datalist.count();
for(conditons)
{
   SaveRecord(datalist); // here just pass one data which you have to save
}

function SaveRecord(datalist)
{
  try{
     // Write your save code here.
  }
  catch(Exception ex){
     // don't throw exception.
  }
}
```

Comment: isn't good for huge data insert? every time i insert would be have about 400,000++ entries

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the unique values inserted, you can do it this was

```
dataList.Distinct(l => l.value).ForEach(i => db.HData.Add(new HData() { Value = i, Time = some.CreateDateTime }));
```

Comment: It maybe duplicate on database data

Comment: Would you be able to make use of a staging table?  Read the data into a temp table in the db, join the data to the destination table, en then insert everything from staging that is not in destination